# Is possible to alter Scoped service from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am pretty much new in Asp.Net Core world and I am playing around with services now. I had an idea to create instance of class I created (named **CourseEditor**) that will be accessible through whole controller (in every action on that very controller). So I added the class as a Scoped service to **Startup.cs** and method **ConfigureServices**:

```
services.AddScoped<CourseEditor>();
```

Now I have my controller **CourseEditorController.cs**.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[ViewLayout("_CourseEditorLayout")]
public class CourseEditorController : Controller
{

    private CourseEditor _courseEditor;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public CourseEditorController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, CourseEditor courseEditor)
    {
        _courseEditor = courseEditor;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OpenCourse(int courseId)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        _courseEditor = await db.LoadCourseForEditByIDAsync(courseId);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_courseEditor);
    }        

    public IActionResult EditHead()
    {

        return View(_courseEditor);
    }
}
```

And I am quite stuck. Because every time I load into this controller, the `_courseEditor` is rewritten to default values. So now I am trying to figure out, how to alter the parameters of the service `CourseEditor` itself so it won't "reset" the `_courseEditor` every time I jump between actions.

So basically I am trying to alter the service `CourseEditor.Title` in controller **CourseEditorController.cs** because it's by default `null` and it's rewriting the `_courseEditor.Title` from actual text  to `null`. Can I do that?

//Edit:
I forgot to explain how the Controller works. So basically when user moves to this "editor" controller, first it goes through action "OpenCourse" that will load all the data as `_courseEditor.Title` and stuff from MySQL Database. But as you can see, after that there is a `RedirectToAction("Index")`. So the `_courseEditor` is run through the **constructor** and there is everything set back to `null` since it's the value that was set when the program was initializing the **service**. Or at least I think this is happening.

Comment: What you want is a singleton. Register your Service as a singleton instead of a scoped.

Comment: Thank you for a good idea! I just tried it but unfortunately it's still changing to null.

Comment: That’s odd... Should not happen, because the instance is keep throughout the lifetime of the application. Scoped only exist per Request.

Comment: I just updated the case with some more details. Well I think it's because of the constructor, because when the service is initialized, the default value for Title and other parameters is "null". And I think in the constructor of this controller the local _courseEditor is being rewritten by that Singleton instance from actual text back to null. I think... I mean I can see in debugger that everything was set but after refresh the courseEditor in controller has everything null.

Comment: Oh! It working but it's a bit strange. I think I am missing something. I just created a view with form to edit the class and it's working like a charm thank you very much! Singleton is the way. It's just... the OpenCourse Action is not capable of permanently altering the courseEditor I guess? I think I am missing something really stupid.

Comment: ähm... You overwrite your service field value basically with the instance from the database. That’s never gonna work. What you want to do does not work with multiple users.

Comment: Yes but that was only for "load existing post for edit" it's not supposed to go through the OpenCourse action every time. It's run through only on the first run.

Comment: Whats the first run? The first run for 1 User? Because after that every user will share one CourseEditor instance with the same id. And if another user calls OpenCourse, that will change it for __all__ user.

Comment: Oh I see... so the Singleton is not the correct way right? Because every user will have the one and exact same instance.

Comment: First that and second the way you do it. Every call to your Api is a new instance of the Controller. Every user can call the same thing at the same time. Keep that in mind and design your Api according that.

Comment: To actually save your situation you can use a ConcurrentDictionary with the user as key and the value is the CourseEditor. That way you can have a separate instance of it for every user.

Comment: This ConcurrentDictionary, I looked that up at asp.net docs. I am wondering, if I create this Dictionary in Controller, it won't create a new instance of service. So in the end the best solution is avoid using services and fill the courseEditor in every Action based on ID that will be stored in GET parameter or Cookie. Am i right?

Comment: The dictionary as a static field. You create the CorseEditor when the user calls OpenCourse, put it in the dictionary. Every other call that has to do with the Course, you just retrieve the CourseEditor from the dictionary. When the same user calls OpenCourse again, you replace the CourseEditor in the dictionary.

Comment: But be aware ... The dictionary will not work anymore if you have multiple web-services and a load balancer. In that case you have to use a distributed cache.

Comment: Well I do have a SignManager in it as well. I just finished writting down the code for the dictionary, so I'll try it out. Well if it won't work I'll just redo the whole editor and let it laod the instance from database on every action. Thank you for your help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is to add the service not as a Scoped service, but as a Singleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<CourseEditor>();
```

Unfortunately for me this does not solve anything since Singleton represents one instance for whole application which means every user will see data from this very instance of editor. They cannot create their "own" instance of editor.

One way how to reach that possibility of creating more instances is via **ConcurrentDictionary** (thank you @Legacy Code for the explanation). More details about this static dictionary is here in Asp.net core docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1

Second way is probably to just recover the data from database on every Action call.

Another way might be to use some kind of transporter as Cookies but this approach is not very secure since User can manipulate with cookies and it might be really hard to store a complex object there.